# Firebase React Native fetch data

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to do an app on react-native with a feed. On my main screen, I go fetch the data :

```
fetchData() {
firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${group}`).on('value', async snapshot => {...}
}
```

when I want for example to like a comment of the post, I first push the data into firebase with different queries, for example :

```
export const likeComment = (...) => {   
firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${group}/${post}`).update
({
   updatedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP 
});
firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${group}/${post}/lastComments`).set(...);
```

But I realized that my first function fetchData was called 3 times.
then I grouped my queries like :

```
let updates = {}
updates[`/posts/${group}/${post}/lastComments`] = {...};
updates[`/posts/${group}/${post}`] = { ... };
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Then, fetchData was called still 2 times.

I was wondering if that was the best way to do it, and why does my function fetchData was still called twice.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the limited code, but my guess is that `fetchData` is not actually being called more than once, but instead the `snapshot` is firing when you make updates to your Firebase database.

The part of your code where you say `.on('value', async snapshot =>` you're setting up a listener to send you updates any time that value changes.

So my guess is that your three invocations are:

1. The first time you actually call fetchData and set up the
   listener
2. Your `.on( snapshot` listener firing when you call
   `update`
3. Your `.on( snapshot` listener firing again when you
   call `set`

This push-based database workflow is one of the main benefits of Firebase. If you only want to get the data once and not get live updates, you can call `.once(` instead of `.on(`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. Indeed, it is the snapshot which is called three times, sorry for that. I want it to refresh so .on( is relevant. When i use one time     set, the snapshot is called once, but when i use one time update it is called twice. Is it normal?

Comment: I would look at the contents of the snapshot that comes back. Are they the same both times when you call update? If not, you're probably doing more work somewhere without realizing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem came from firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP which returns two values.